# SQL Join Help - Sum and Apply Filter to Tables Before Join

Tags: sql, join, filter, sum

I have a Stock View (that lists all the individual pieces of stock and the stock date) and a Sales View (that lists all of the sales and the date the sale occurred).

Stock View:

```
+----+------+-----+------------+
| ID | Item | Qty |    Date    |
+----+------+-----+------------+
|  1 | A    |   3 | 01/01/2000 |
|  2 | A    |   2 | 02/02/2000 |
|  3 | D    |   9 | 05/06/2000 |
|  4 | F    |  22 | 09/01/2001 |
|  5 | A    |  10 | 01/04/2001 |
|  6 | C    |  12 | 01/01/2002 |
+----+------+-----+------------+
```

Sales View:

```
+------+-----+------------+
| Item | Qty |    Date    |
+------+-----+------------+
| B    |   3 | 01/01/2001 |
| B    |  77 | 01/12/2001 |
| C    |   9 | 02/02/2002 |
| A    |  10 | 03/03/2002 |
| G    |   2 | 05/06/2002 |
| C    |   3 | 09/10/2012 |
+------+-----+------------+
```

I want to join these tables..but before doing so:

Stock view needs to be filtered between 2 date parameters @StockFrom and @StockTo

Sales view needs to be filtered between 2 date parameters @SalesFrom and @SalesTo

Sales view then needs to be grouped by Item and have the Qty Summed (so the date field needs to be dropped although it is being filtered on) and then joined onto the Stock View on the Item field.

So in essence I want to see the Stock View as it is (but filtered on dates) with an extra column showing the sales that have occurred between 2 dates for that item.

Desired Output:

```
+----+------+-----+------------+-------+
| ID | Item | Qty |    Date    | Sales |
+----+------+-----+------------+-------+
|  1 | A    |   3 | 01/01/2000 |    10 |
|  2 | A    |   2 | 02/02/2000 |    10 |
|  3 | D    |   9 | 05/06/2000 |     0 |
|  4 | F    |  22 | 09/01/2001 |     0 |
|  5 | A    |  10 | 01/04/2001 |    10 |
|  6 | C    |  12 | 01/01/2002 |    12 |
+----+------+-----+------------+-------+
```

Thanks to any help in advance!

Comment: What is the type of your `Date` fields?

Comment: You really should try something yourself before asking here (or if you have tried something, show it). [so] is not a query-writing service.

Comment: Which is your database? MS SQL server or MySql or Oracle or...?

Comment: @Nalaka526 - Date fields are Datetime

Comment: @techdo - MS SQL Server (2005)

Comment: @TomJenkin Okay... Please check the added answer.

Comment: If the sales table does not share the ID column how are the two tables related when the Item column is not unique in the stock table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
  Stock.*,
  IFNULL(SUM(Sales.Qty),0) AS Sales
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN Sales ON Stock.Item=Sales.Item
WHERE Stock.Date BETWEEN @StockFrom AND @StockTo
AND (
  Sales.Date BETWEEN @SalesFrom AND @SalesTo
  OR Sales.Date IS NULL
)
GROUP BY Stock.ID
```

This is for MySQL, as you didn't specify the diaclect. [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ac16)

**EDIT**

```
SELECT
  Stock.ID AS ID,
  MIN(Stock.Item) AS Item,
  MIN(Stock.Qty) AS Qty,
  MIN(Stock.Date) AS Date,
  CASE WHEN SUM(Sales.Qty) IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE SUM(Sales.Qty) END AS Sales
FROM Stock
LEFT JOIN Sales ON Stock.Item=Sales.Item
WHERE Stock.Date BETWEEN @StockFrom AND @StockTo
AND (
  Sales.Date BETWEEN @SalesFrom AND @SalesTo
  OR Sales.Date IS NULL
)
GROUP BY Stock.ID
```

works for MS SQL ([SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/070ae/10))

Comment: Thanks for this Eugen, can we not filter and sum the sales before joining, I'm worried about the efficiency as both tables will contain a lot of rows.
EDIT: So the Sales Table will effectively have 1 row per item showing the total sales for a defined period before joining onto the Stock Table.

Comment: @TomJenkin We DO filter the tables before - look at the execution plan.

Comment: I've just implemented this query and it seems to work really well! Thankyou :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query for MS Sql Server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.ID, 
    a.Item, 
    a.Qty, 
    a.Date, 
    ISNULL(SUM(b.Qty) OVER (PARTITION BY a.Item, a.[Date]), 0) Sales
FROM 
    StockView a LEFT JOIN SalesView b on a.Item=b.Item
```